# CC430 - NodeMCU I2C Communication Problem

Tags: i2c, msp430

I'm trying to communicate CC430 microcontroller based board with ESP8266(NodeMCU). I can communicate in one-direction e.g. NodeMCU to CC430. However I can't send any character CC430 to NodeMCU board. What could be the problem? Connections are done properly e.g. Vcc--> Vcc , GND --> GND , SDA --> SDA , SCL --> SCL .
There are also pull - up resistors. I tried the Arduino to NodeMCU communication , there is no problem with that. However neither Arduino nor NodeMCU can't get any character from CC430 side.

Code is given with link : https://dev.ti.com/tirex/explore/node?node=ALKC78J64Cwe6EXqBJh1DQ__IOGqZri__LATEST

Comment: Which device is master, which is slave? What I2C address does the slave have? What I2C address does the master send? Are both addresses in the same format (7 bit, or 8 bit inc. RW)?

Comment: When CC430 is master sender and NodeMCU is slave receiver I have a problem. Slave I2C address is 0x48 , master sends to this address[on the given link I'm using 0x48 as slave address]. I assume both using 7 bit addressing mode but I'm not sure.  CC430 can supply this information in datasheet and I can change it to 10 or 7 bit addressing mode but in NodeMCU I don't know how can I do that operation.

Comment: Note to other readers interested in this topic: The same question is currently active in a duplicate thread [here on the TI E2E forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/968154), where additional information has been added.